# Field variable produces different result than local variable with recursion

Tags: java, variables, global-variables

I had this very strange problem and I am not sure why.

```
public class QuickSort
{
  private int pivLocation;
  private void quickSort(Integer[] input, int low, int high)
  {
    if(low < high)
    {
      this.pivLocation = partition(input, low, high);
      quickSort(input, low, pivLocation-1);
      quickSort(input, pivLocation+1, high);
      Inversions.comparisons += high - low;
    }
  }
}

private int partition(Integer[] input, int low, int high)
{

        int arrLength = high - low;

        if(arrLength%2 == 0){

            int pivot = input[low];
        }
        else
        {
            int pivot = 1;
        }
    int i = low+1;
    for(int j=low+1; j<= high; j++ )
    {

        if(input[j]< pivot)
        {

            swap(input, j, i);
            i++;
        }
    }
    swap(input, low, i-1);

    return i-1;


}
```

This gives a different comparisons count compared to writing the exact same code but instead of using a field variable I turn pivLocation to a local variable.

```
int pivLocation = partition(input, low, high);
```

I don't get why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a class variable, consider the below:

```
pivLocation = partition(input,low,high);
// pivLocation changes in this function (specifically to a lower value)
quickSort(input, low, pivLocation-1);
// pivLocation is now lower than expected
quickSort(input, pivLocation+1, high);
```

Thus the second `quickSort` is called with indices that may include elements that have already been sorted. Thus the number of comparisons will be higher than the required.

When you use a local variable, each the recursive call has it's own `pivLocation` variable, so you don't have this problem.

Comment: The strange thing however is that the sorting is done correctly. Only the comparisons are wrong. If pivLocation is  not correct sorting should fail also. Shouldn't it?

Comment: @idipous From the first recursive call, `pivLocation` can only get a smaller value (easy to see from a brief analysis). This means that you'll be calling `quickSort` for indices that contains some already sorted data. Thus sorting should be successful. Swapping the two recursive calls should cause sorting to fail.

Comment: hmmm, It doesn't fail even when I swap the recursive calls. It still sorts correctly. The only thing wrong is the comparisons. The way I understand it is that as you correctly said pivLocation changes in the first recursive call but because it is changed by -1 when I call the second recursive function I add 1 and because of the way I have partition implemented it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @idipous I can't see why it would sort correctly when the calls are swapped (at least not from the code provided). What do you mean the comparisons are wrong?

Comment: I added the partition code. By comparisons I mean the Inversions.comparisons which is the number of comparisons done by quicksort. When I use the local variable instead of the class field I get the number expected otherwise I get a wrong number.

Comment: @idipous It only sorts correctly after having made a change to `partition` (before that it was giving the incorrect output). [Old](http://ideone.com/1wjkMw), [new](http://ideone.com/GfjRZd).

Answer (score 3):

Because of the recursion. The local variable is initialized each time the method is called.

When you have:

```
int var;
void mymethod() {
   mymethod();
}
```

`var` is initialized only once.

Wtih

```
void mymethod() {
   int var;
   mymethod();
}
```

`var` is initialised (set to zero) each time `mymethod()` is called, due to the fact that the variable scope is limited within the method.